# Is cudaHostRegister equivalent to mlock() system call?

Tags: c, linux, memory, cuda

Pinned or page-locked memory is transferred faster to GPUs compared to not-locked memory.
CUDA provides the `cudaHostAlloc` and `cudaHostRegister` calls to allocate or register page-locked memory. The Nvidia driver then checks upon a memory transfer if the host memory is locked and issues according copy code paths.

Is it possible to page-lock memory with the system call `mlock()` achieving exactly the same effect (regards to transfer speeds) as `cudaHostRegister` ? Or does the according CUDA call update an internal database which the driver queries?

Comment: The update may be added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the NVIDIA driver maintains its own page-locked memory accessible via `cudaHostAlloc` etc. The system call `mlock` uses the kernel locking which is technically equivalent to what the driver does, but the kernel page-locking is *very* resource restricted `RLIMIT_MEMLOCK` which is very small. Thus NVIDIA driver uses its own page-locking mechanism. And they warn about excessive usage, since it steals lots of memory accessible to the rest of the kernel.

So, `cudaHostRegister` is equivalent to `mlock()` in the sense that it page-locks memory, but not in the sense that it is bound to resource limitations. And not in the sense, that `cudaMemcpy` is accelerated.

Answer (score 2):

They are not equivalent.  cuMemHostRegister() page-locks the memory, but also maps it into the page tables of the GPU (or, if portable, GPUs) so the GPU can access it directly.  If you page-lock memory without mapping it for the GPU, it looks to the GPU just like any other memory.